# How to make circumflexes wider but still of a fixed size in XeTeX?

Tags: math-mode, xetex, accents

Circumflexes looks too small and they are to close to the symbol in the PDF generated by XeLaTeX from `UTF-8` source with [Asana Math](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/asana-math) font for mathematics:

[image]

Source:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO,bold-style=ISO,nabla=upright,partial=upright,vargreek-shape=unicode]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{[Asana-Math]}

\newcommand*{\op}[1]{\hat{\mathup{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \op{H} = \op{T} + \op{V} 
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I want to make circumflexes wider to be more clearly separated from the symbols underneath them, but `\widehat` is not an option since it produces circumflexes of variable size. 
The solution in [How can I manually choose the size of a wide accent? (math mode)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20473/how-can-i-manually-choose-the-size-of-a-wide-accent-math-mode) doesn't work for me. Seems like there is some incompatibility between the [`accents`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/accents) package and `UTF-8` encoding.

I really like Asana Math, so I don't want to change the font.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe it might be worth a try to introduce two commands via the `xparse` package:

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\operator}{ s m }{
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{
                    \widehat{#2}
            }{
                    \hat{#2}}
            }
    }
```

Then `\operator{H}` gives the "normal" output and `\operator*{H}` stretches the circumflex.

Maybe you want to look also at the following post: [Really wide hat symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100574/really-wide-hat-symbol) where the `scalerel` package is used. You might think of defining a command with two inputs, the first one giving then the width of the hat, and the second as the character

**Edit:**

I think I have now a solution after looking at [`source2e.pdf`](http://ctan.org/topic/latex-doc) and [`encguide.pdf`](http://ctan.org/topic/latex-doc).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO,bold-style=ISO,nabla=upright,partial=upright,vargreek-shape=unicode]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{[Asana-Math]}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mylargesymbols}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAccent{\mywidehat}{\mathord}{mylargesymbols}{"62}
\begin{document}
$\hat{\mathrm{H}} = \hat{\mathrm{T}} + \hat{\mathrm{V}} +\hat{abcdefgh}$

$ \widehat{\mathrm{H}} = \widehat{\mathrm{T}} + \widehat{\mathrm{V}} +\widehat{abcdefgh}$

$ \mywidehat{\mathrm{H}} = \mywidehat{\mathrm{T}} + \mywidehat{\mathrm{V}} +\mywidehat{abcdefgh}$
\end{document}
```

will give the following result

[image]

The hat still expands, but not so dramatic as case before.

Comment: Magnificent! :)

Comment: Great solution - it turns out this is useful with the Neo Euler font as well.  The otf version seems to lack stretchy accents, so it's very handy to have this method to pick the accents up from `cmex`.

Answer (score 1):

[NOTE: Edit 1 for better vertical positioning; Edit 2 for "hat" not "wedge"] I don't have access to your particular fonts, so I address the problem for the default LaTeX font.  You will have to reparameterize my solution.  It involves using the `scalerel` package for stretching the `\hat` symbol (`\char'136`).  I show the unmodified result and then the result for one parameters-set of stretches.  Once you calibrate the three parameters for your font, lock those values into the definition.  `\Ht` defines the vertical stretch; `\Wd` defines the horizontal stretch; and `\Dp` defines the vertical separation multiplier between letter and overhat.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\newlength\svarraycolsep
\newcommand\althat[1]{%
\renewcommand\arraystretch{\Dp}%
\setlength\svarraycolsep{\arraycolsep}%
\setlength\arraycolsep{0in}%
\begin{array}{c}%
  \vstretch{\Ht}{%
    \hstretch{\Wd}{%
      \trimbox{.15ex .75ex .15ex .2ex}{\scalerel*{\char'136}{\rule{1ex}{1ex}}}%
    }%
  }\\%
  #1\\%
\rule{1ex}{0ex}\\%
\end{array}%
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.0}%
\setlength\arraycolsep{\svarraycolsep}%
}

\parindent 0in
\begin{document}

Hat:

\( \hat{\mathrm{H}} = \hat{\mathrm{T}} + \hat{\mathrm{V}} \)

Carat(char'136):


\def\Ht{1.8}
\def\Wd{4.5}
\def\Dp{.3}
\( \althat {\mathrm{H}} = \althat {\mathrm{T}} + \althat {\mathrm{V}} \)

\end{document}
```

[image]