# \hat and \bar compatibility issue EDIT: It's a bug, workaround provided

Tags: formatting, amsmath, incompatibility

I have two `\newcommand` defined as follows:

```
\newcommand{\hvar}[1]{\hat{\delta #1}}
\newcommand{\gbp}{{{\bar{\gamma}}_p}}
```

And they look like this:

`\hvar{X}` [image: \hvar{X}]

`\gbp` [image: \gbp]

The problem is that, if I use them together I get this:

`\hvar{\gbp}` [image: \hvar{\gbp}]

It seems like the `\gamma` was shifted to the right.
Is this a bug? Is there a way to fix it?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\hvar}[1]{\hat{\delta #1}}
\newcommand{\gbp}{{{\bar{\gamma}}_p}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\hvar{X} \qquad \gbp \qquad \hvar{\gbp}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

---

## EDIT:

As egreg mentioned, this is a bug on the accent implementation of `amsmath`. A work around is provided here: [Why do arguments to nested \tilde or \breve commands reappear when amsmath is used?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30327) and a MWE presented below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newsavebox{\accentbox}
\newcommand{\compacc}[2]{\sbox\accentbox{$#2$}#1{\usebox\accentbox}}
\newcommand{\compaccX}[2]{\let\accenttemp#1\mathpalette\docompacc{#2}}
\def\docompacc#1#2{\compacc\accenttemp{#1#2}}

\newcommand{\hvar}[1]{\compaccX{\hat}{\delta #1}}
\newcommand{\gbp}{{{\bar{\gamma}}_p}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\hvar{X} \qquad \gbp \qquad \hvar{\gbp} \qquad A_{\hvar{\gbp}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Looks like:

[image]

Comment: I can't really provide any technical insights on this one, but I will observe that replacing `\hat` with `\widehat` seems to work, if that's an acceptable solution.

Comment: `\hat` and `\bar` are accents. Combining multiple accents onto one character is one of the "scary" parts of TeX.

Comment: Are you planning on using this symbol combination in subscripts/superscripts?

Comment: Yes. I will need a `\dot{\gbp}` in a subscript, which has the same problem.

Comment: I believe this is a bug in the accent implementation of `amsmath`. `:-(` Some macros that are set globally disrupt the working of the inner accent. This can be seen by trying `\hvar{\text{$\gbp$}}` which produces the dreaded undefined control sequence error about `\macc@kerna`. See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30327/why-do-arguments-to-nested-tilde-or-breve-commands-reappear-when-amsmath-is-us

Comment: Thank you egreg! I'll Edit my question to mention the bug and the workaround from your link!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative using a homegrown `\althat` routine, with three defining parameters (`\Ht`, `\Wd`, and `\Dp`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\newcommand{\hvar}[1]{\althat{\delta #1}}
\newcommand{\gbp}{{{\bar{\gamma}}_p}}

\newlength\svarraycolsep
\newcommand\althat[1]{%
\renewcommand\arraystretch{\Dp}%
\setlength\svarraycolsep{\arraycolsep}%
\setlength\arraycolsep{0in}%
\begin{array}{c}%
  \vstretch{\Ht}{%
    \hstretch{\Wd}{%
      \trimbox{.15ex .75ex .15ex .2ex}{\scalerel*{\char'136}{\rule{1ex}{1ex}}}%
    }%
  }\\%
  #1\\%
\rule{1ex}{0ex}\\%
\end{array}%
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.0}%
\setlength\arraycolsep{\svarraycolsep}%
}

\parindent 0in
\begin{document}

\def\Ht{1.8}
\def\Wd{4.5}
\def\Dp{.3}
\( \althat {\mathrm{H}} = \althat {\mathrm{T}} + \althat {\mathrm{V}} \)

\( \hvar{X} \qquad \gbp \qquad \hvar{\gbp} \)

\end{document}
```

[image]

As originally proposed at [How to make circumflexes wider but still of a fixed size in XeTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107881/how-to-make-circumflexes-wider-but-still-of-a-fixed-size-in-xetex/108196#108196)