# \hat with \bar in subscript when using amsmath

Tags: subscripts

I want to have the variance symbol (sigma squared) with an {X with bar} in the subscript and a hat on top of everything. The following code produces a mess (The X is not subscripted). Can anyone tell me why? (Using \overline instead of \bar is not an option.)

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$\hat{\sigma^2_{\bar{X}}}$

\end{document}
```

[image: X aligned with sigma]

Comment: It's a known bug in `amsmath` when accents are nested. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132450/hat-and-bar-compatibility-issue-edit-its-a-bug-workaround-provided and linked threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't explain why the problem arises in the first place, but one solution is to box the initial item, and apply the `\hat` at the end.  I also provide a 2nd alternative where I apply the `\hat` only to the `\sigma`; that may be preferable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$
\setbox0=\hbox{$\sigma^2_{\bar{X}}$}
\hat{\box0}
$
$\setbox0=\hbox{$\hat\sigma$}\box0^2_{\bar{X}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If one wanted the first approach, but with a really wide hat, my answer at [Really wide hat symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100574/really-wide-hat-symbol/101136#101136) might be applicable:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel,stackengine}
\stackMath
\newcommand\reallywidehat[1]{%
\savestack{\tmpbox}{\stretchto{%
  \scaleto{%
    \scalerel*[\widthof{\ensuremath{#1}}]{\kern-.6pt\bigwedge\kern-.6pt}%
    {\rule[-\textheight/2]{1ex}{\textheight}}%WIDTH-LIMITED BIG WEDGE
  }{\textheight}% 
}{0.5ex}}%
\stackon[1pt]{#1}{\tmpbox}%
}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$
\reallywidehat{\sigma^2_{\bar{X}}}
$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, Steven. Your first solution produces what I wanted. I was waiting for a nicer solution, but since, according to egreg, this is a bug, I accept your workaround :)

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$\widehat{\sigma_{\bar X}^2}$
\end{document}
```

or are you referring to the fact that `\bar X` is not aligned with the 2.  For that you can use `\!` albeit that there are more sophisticated solutions (kerning).

Comment: apparently it only happens when I include amsmath. I updated the question. The problem is that the X is aligned with sigma, it doesn't look like a subscript