# Rescaling \widecheck Accent

Tags: math-mode, accents

This is essentially a repost of [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20473/how-can-i-manually-choose-the-size-of-a-wide-accent-math-mode) question but for the `\check` symbol:

I would like to replace the usual `\check` in maths with a larger one, but I do not want it to stretch. The size I want is "the smallest `\widecheck`" (as in `$\widecheck{.}$`). Is there a way to put that one above a wide character like M (`$\widecheck{M}$` would stretch and give be an even wider check).

My main problem seems to be that I cannot find a corresponding symbol for \widecheck in the largesymbols font family.

---

Here is one workaround I was able to get. There is probably a simpler way.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,accents}    

\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{
          <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10>
          <10.95> <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88>
          mathx10
          }{}
    \DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
    \DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
    \DeclareMathAccent{\widecheck}{0}{mathx}{"71}
    \DeclareMathAccent{\wideparen}{0}{mathx}{"75}
    
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\widechecksym}{\mathord}{mathx}{"71}
    \newcommand\lowerwidechecksym{%
      \text{\smash{\hspace*{-0.25ex}\raisebox{-1.1ex}{%
        $\widechecksym$}}}}
    \newcommand\wcheck[1]{%
      \mathchoice
        {\accentset{\displaystyle\lowerwidechecksym}{#1}}
        {\accentset{\textstyle\lowerwidechecksym}{#1}}
        {\accentset{\scriptstyle\lowerwidechecksym}{#1}}
        {\accentset{\scriptscriptstyle\lowerwidechecksym}{#1}}
    }
    
    
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\widehatsym}{\mathord}{mathx}{"70}
    \newcommand\lowerwidehatsym{%
      \text{\smash{\hspace*{-0.25ex}\raisebox{-1.1ex}{%
        $\widehatsym$}}}}
    \newcommand\what[1]{%
      \mathchoice
        {\accentset{\displaystyle\lowerwidehatsym}{#1}}
        {\accentset{\textstyle\lowerwidehatsym}{#1}}
        {\accentset{\scriptstyle\lowerwidehatsym}{#1}}
        {\accentset{\scriptscriptstyle\lowerwidehatsym}{#1}}
    }

\end{document}
```

Comment: A wide check accent does not exist because it would be very problematic to understand what it refers to; the hat instead covers making usually clear what is its extent. On the other hand, I'd not recommend using very wide checks, for the same readability reason.

Comment: @egreg Maybe I'm misunderstanding your comment, but \widecheck does exist as part of the mathx font family. I just haven't been able to get it working as in the linked post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean this?

[image]

I find it awful and difficult to read, but you're the judge. Here's the code for importing the accent from `mathabx`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{ <-> mathx10 }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathAccent{\widecheck}{0}{mathx}{"71}

\begin{document}

$\check{a}\widecheck{aa}\widecheck{aaa}\widecheck{aaaa}\widecheck{aaaaa}$

\end{document}
```

If you just want the shortest wide check, the following code emulates the accent placement but is only apt for Latin letters. It *could* be extended also for Greek letters.

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{ <-> mathx10 }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathAccent{\widecheck}{0}{mathx}{"71}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\wcheck}[1]{\mathpalette\wcheck@{#1}}
\newcommand{\wcheck@}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \edef\wcheck@font{\the
    \ifx#1\displaystyle\textfont\else\ifx#1\textstyle\textfont
    \else\ifx#1\scriptstyle\scriptfont\else\scriptscriptfont\fi\fi\fi\@ne
  }%
  \sbox\z@{\wcheck@font\mbox{#2}\mbox{\char\the\skewchar\font}}%
  \sbox\tw@{\wcheck@font#2\char\the\skewchar\font}%
  \dimen@=\dimexpr\wd\tw@-\wd\z@\relax
  {\,\kern2\dimen@\widecheck{\!\kern-2\dimen@#2\!}\,}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\wcheck{M}$ $\wcheck{A}$

$\check{M}$ $\widecheck{A}$

\end{document}
```

In the example I use `\check` over `M` just to show that the accent placement is right.

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{ <-> mathx10 }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathAccent{\widecheck}{0}{mathx}{"71}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\wcheck}[1]{\mathpalette\wcheck@{#1}}
\newcommand{\wcheck@}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \edef\wcheck@font{\the
    \ifx#1\displaystyle\textfont\else\ifx#1\textstyle\textfont
    \else\ifx#1\scriptstyle\scriptfont\else\scriptscriptfont\fi\fi\fi\@ne
  }%
  \sbox\z@{\wcheck@font\mbox{#2}\mbox{\char\the\skewchar\font}}%
  \sbox\tw@{\wcheck@font#2\char\the\skewchar\font}%
  \dimen@=\dimexpr\wd\tw@-\wd\z@\relax
  {\,\kern2\dimen@\widecheck{\!\kern-2\dimen@#2\!}\,}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\wcheck{M}$ $\wcheck{A}$
$\scriptstyle\wcheck{M}\scriptstyle\check{M}$
$\scriptstyle\wcheck{A}\scriptstyle\widecheck{A}$

$\check{M}$ $\widecheck{A}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

An altogether different method is outlined below.

1. Copy `mathx10.tfm` to `mathxy10.tfm` in the working directory; on a Unix system with `bash` or similar shell,

   ```
   cp $(kpsewhich mathx10.tfm) mathxy10.tfm
   ```
2. Convert the `.tfm` file into `.pl`

   ```
   tftopl mathxy10.tfm > mathxy10.pl
   ```
3. Edit the file just created to find the entries with `CHARACTER C p` and `CHARACTER C q` to remove the `NEXTLARGER` property from both (just remove the line)
4. Convert the `.pl` file back to `.tfm`

   ```
   pltotf mathxy10.pl
   ```
5. Add at the beginning of you TeX file the line

   ```
   \pdfmapline{+mathxy10 TeX-mathx10 <mathx10.pfb}
   ```
6. Use the newly created font file as symbol font

Example

```
\pdfmapline{+mathxy10 TeX-mathx10 <mathx10.pfb}

\documentclass{article}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{ <-> mathxy10 }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathAccent{\what}{0}{mathx}{"70}
\DeclareMathAccent{\wcheck}{0}{mathx}{"71}

\begin{document}

$\wcheck{M}\wcheck{A}$

$\what{M}\what{A}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

These are the edits to do in the `.pl` file

Before

```
(CHARACTER C p
   (CHARWD R 0.55542)
   (CHARHT R 0.722046)
   (NEXTLARGER C x)
   )
(CHARACTER C q
   (CHARWD R 0.55542)
   (CHARHT R 0.722046)
   (NEXTLARGER O 174)
   )
```

After:

```
(CHARACTER C p
   (CHARWD R 0.55542)
   (CHARHT R 0.722046)
   )
(CHARACTER C q
   (CHARWD R 0.55542)
   (CHARHT R 0.722046)
   )
```

Comment: No. I want the \widecheck to always remain the same size, but be larger than \check.

Comment: @Mobius Added for Latin letters. I also add a different method.

Comment: The first method seems to be working, but I really need it for Greek letters as well. Is this a simple fix?