# Erroneous width of widetilde, scrartcl, amsmath, lmodern

Tags: math-mode, fontsize, lmodern

Depending on the combination of packages loaded, the width of `\widetilde` can be erroneous.

I guess this is a bug in koma, but it as also somehow affected by the package lmodern, albeit only when combined with koma.

I assume I need to find a replacement for `lmodern` or quit using koma.
Is there another remedy?

**0. Desired output**

```
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage{amsmath}  % does not make a difference
% \usepackage{lmodern}  % does not make a difference
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\widetilde{c_x'} \widetilde{c_y'}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: desired]

**1. KOMA without amsmath**

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\widetilde{c_x'} \widetilde{c_y'}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: erroneous]

**2. KOMA with amsmath**

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\widetilde{c_x'} \widetilde{c_y'}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: desired]

**3. KOMA with lmodern (with or without amsmath)**

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
% \usepackage{amsmath}  % does not make a difference
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\widetilde{c_x'} \widetilde{c_y'}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: erroneous]

Comment: The default font size of `article` is 10pt. The default font size of `scrartcl` is 11pt. If you use `\documentclass[10pt]{scrartcl}` you get the same result as with `\documentclass{article}` (as wanted). And if you use `\documentclass[11pt]{article}` you get the same result as with `\documentclass{scrartcl}` (as not wanted). So this does not depend on using a KOMA-Script class or not, but on the font sizes.

Comment: Ah I see, font size was the one aspect I did not consider checking. Setting `\documentclass[11pt]{article}` indeed produces the same weird appearance. `\usepackage{amsmath}` fixes that, but `\usepackage{lmodern}` then destroys that fix again. So I guess it is a side effect of `lmodern`.

Answer (score 5):

You forgot one option, namely `fixcmex`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fixcmex} % does make a difference

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\widetilde{c_x'} \widetilde{c_y'}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The difference you see with KOMA-Script only appears because KOMA-Script use `11pt` fonts by default, while `article` uses `10pt`. Load the `article` class with `11pt` you'll see the same thing.

`\widetilde` is a math accent which extends according to its content.
In your case, `x` is slightly larger than `y`, and the larger form is used with `11pt` fonts (it's the same, if you use `m` as subscript). The simplest you can do is to move the subscripts outside `\widehat`:

```tex
\begin{equation}
  \widetilde{c'}_{\! x} \widetilde{c'}_{\! y}
\end{equation}
```

[image: widetitle shorter]

Comment: Some seconds earlier. ;-)

Comment: @cabohah I saw at validation. Sorry.

Comment: BTW: I can remember, that there was already a similar question some time ago. But I was not able to find it. So maybe it is good to once again have this question/answer.

Comment: Ok, makes sense, but the large space preceding the subscript versus the small space after it is really awkward.

Comment: @Bastian You right. I tweaked a bit the space with `\!` but it's not perfect. Otherwise see [How can I manually choose the size of a wide accent? (math mode)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20473/316068).